# How to Additional Items in Scrum 1.0 Template

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs, scrum

I am new to Visual Studio Scrum 1.0 Template. Created a Team project with Scrum 1.0 Template. After that in TFS a Team work Item menu is having following work items

1. Bug
2. List item
3. Impediment
4. Product Backlog Item
5. Shared Steps
6. Sprint
7. Task
8. Test Status

however, in my organization another project is having some of additional work items like follow

1. Code Review Item
2. Release
3. Acceptance Test
4. Sprint Retrospective
5. Sprint Backlog Task

Do we need to modify any setting in TFS Server to bring this above items?
Please guide to proceed further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Code Review Item" might be in correlation with [TFS Code review workflow](http://tfscodereviewflow.codeplex.com/). If so, it would require you to insert it in each new TeamProject for the while thing to be usable.
All other Work Item types do not ring any bell to me, so my best guess is that they are custom types.
In order for you to import them in your newly constructed TeamProject you need to have the latest [Power tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963) installed.
Open VS and navigate to "Tools">"Process Editor">"Work Item Types">"Export WIT". Select the old Team Project & export to your PC the XMLs that correspond to each of your missing types.
Once you are done, use "Import WIT" to insert these XMLs into your new TeamProject. This should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Those other items must be from a different template. They're not part of the Microsoft Scrum Template.